# How to query SQL SERVER for the current date

Tags: sql-server

I have templates that are autocompleted with data using placeholders in the form of `##ClientFirstName##`, `##..something else..##`. I have a `XML` file where I keep sql query for each placeholder so I can automate the process fo generating documents from those templates.

For instance for `##ClientFirstName##` I have this query associated -

`SELECT FirstName FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Clients] WHERE Id = @param`.

So far so good. What I have to do for most of the templates is to insert the current date so I have placeholder `##DateTimeNow##` but right now the `SQL` associated with it is:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120) AS CurrentDate
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Clients]
```

This works well but it just seems strange. I'm pretty sure there should be way to get only the date without refering any particular table. The only requirement here is to be able to format the result as it is in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit shorter:

```
SELECT {fn curdate()}
```

Or this

```
SELECT Convert(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Note that `DATE` was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Why that table needed there ??

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),120)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just a straight select statement

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120) AS CurrentDate
```